# ggplot2 not showing all lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

We are working on some ggplot2 graphs. Each graph contains multiple lines. However, when our line number exceeds more than 3 lines, there are only 3 lines showing in the graph, and the rest lines are gone. The weird thing is that the legends are all there.

[image]

Here is the snapshot of the code:

```
     tailStretchPlot[[i]] <- ggplot() +
        geom_step(data=tmp, aes(x=SizeCumPercent-SizeCntPercent/2,
        y=TailStretch, width=SizeCntPercent, colour=TransportType), size=4)

    plotTitle <- paste(append(unlist(strsplit(plotTitle, split='')), '\n',
        as.integer(nchar(plotTitle)/2)), sep='', collapse='')

    xIntervals <- findInterval(c(0)+seq(2,102,10),
        tmp[tmp$TransportType=='homa',]$SizeCumPercent)

    tailStretchPlot[[i]] <- tailStretchPlot[[i]] +
        theme(text = element_text(size=1.5*textSize),
            axis.text = element_text(size=1.3*textSize),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle=75, vjust=0.5),
            strip.text = element_text(size = textSize),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 1.2*titleSize,
            color='darkblue'), plot.margin=unit(c(2,2,2.5,2.2),"cm"),
            legend.position = c(0.1, 0.85),
            legend.text = element_text(size=1.5*textSize)) +
        guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=textSize/4)))+
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,101),
            breaks = tmp[xIntervals,]$SizeCumPercent,
            labels=tmp[xIntervals,]$MsgSizeRange, expand = c(0, 0)) +
        scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,10,15)) +
        coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1, yLimit)) +
        labs(title = plotTitle, y = yLab, x = xLab)
```

The GitHub link is the complete script and sample data txt file:

https://github.com/Stanley131/ggplot2_issue

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: please make your question reproducible by including a sample of your data. Also your image hasn't worked

Comment: Does it work correctly if you make the plot outside of a loop?  It's going to be easier for folks to help if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Be careful setting limits on `scale_x_continuous()`, any data outside those limits will get dropped.

Comment: Hey, guys. Sorry for providing enough information for the question. I just add the complete script link and sample dataset to my GitHub. https://github.com/Stanley131/ggplot2_issue. Thanks again.